# java How to initialize Annotation dynamicly

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have the following structure :

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntitySequence {

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="X?" )
@SequenceGenerator( allocationSize = 1, name = "X?" )
@Column( name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true )
private Long id;
```

and child Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "BANK" )
public class Bank extends AbstractEntitySequence implements Serializable {
...
}
```

and other Entities.

I need each entity to have a SEQUENCE generator name and I do not want place it in each Entity (as ^C ^V) 
Is it possible somehow initialize annotation in Abstract class from children class (replace X1) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the [@SequenceGenerator](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html) in one entity class only and it will be available for all entities, because according to the JavaDoc:

> The scope of the generator name is global to the persistence unit
>   (across all generator types).

So, this is how your mapping should look like:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="X", allocationSize=1)
public class Bank {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="X")
    @Id long id;
}

@Entity
public class InsuranceCompany {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="X")
    @Id long id;
}
```